# How did the "b" get in "debt"?

Tags: etymology, historical-change, silent-letters

According to both my trusted sources (wiktionary and etymonline), the word *debt* ("something owed") traces to the Middle English word *dette*, which goes back to *dett*, from the French etymon *dete*. I was wondering how a silent *b* got placed into the word; how come we don't have *det* or something similar? I know the Latin word this stems from was *debere*; did this influence the evolution of the word, or was some medieval scholar trying to be fancy, as occurred to so many similar words?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably the same way it got into "doubt" (Old French _doter_) (Latin _dubitare_)

Comment: Very unusual case.  This word actually originated from frogs.  They would sit on their lily pads and say "debbit".  When humans adopted it, it was shortened to "debt".  I know this is true because I read it on the Internet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Why does English spelling use silent letters?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8883/why-does-english-spelling-use-silent-letters)* — I guess Noldorin must have forgotten :).Also see *[Rationale behind pronunciation of “subtle”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152756)* and *[Are there other words with the same weird spelling / pronunciation combo as “victual”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34568)*

Comment: @choster: Oh my, I had no idea I'd made a similar answer before. It was over 6 years ago to be fair however, so I hope you'll let me off. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The etymology in my edition of the OED is given as follows, and confirms your suspicion.

> Middle English dette: from Old French, based on Latin debitum ‘something owed’, past participle of debere ‘owe’. The spelling change in French and English was by association with the Latin word.

So indeed, the spelling inherited from Old French was modified by influence of Latin. This most likely occurred during the Renaissance, or even slightly later, with the renewed interest in the Classical (Latin) world. Many spellings were modified from around the 15th century to the 19th century under this influence, reverting the pronunciation shifts reflected by the vulgarisation of Latin over many centuries, which very often included dropping of (hard) vowels or elision of silent *h*s, to name but a couple of changes.

In fact, this phenomenon wasn't limited to English, and was extremely prevalent in Spanish (albeit much less so in Italian).

Comment: I ache over our receipt of such unsubtle reforms. Indict me, but I would take scissors to those manuscripts, flee to some arctic isle, and plumb them to the depths.

Comment: @choster, Haha, very good! There must be about 10 instances in that sentence... and perhaps I missed one or two.

Comment: I got ten too, hilarious!