# What is the importance of silent letters in English language?

Tags: silent-letters

How did the usage of silent letters came into being? For example : what is the use of 'k' in knife or 'p' in pneumonia ?

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8883/why-does-english-spelling-use-silent-letters